# Anythingslider with custom FX, the FX object to be inserted from the left, but leave the slide to the right

Tags: anythingslider

I use anythingslider with customFX. When I have an object inserted from the left, it disappears to the same direction. What if I want to appears from left but disappears to right?

Answer (score 0):

The FX extension was written to do some fairly basic animation, so it doesn't *yet* have an option to allow animating in from one direction and out in another.

That being said, you can use the built in callback function to animate the element as desired - check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/3259/):

```
var fxtime = 1000,
    dist = 300,
    element = 'h3';

$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // custom FX animation
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
        // this could be in the css; but added here for emphasis
        slider.$el.find(element).css('position', 'relative');
        // move title to starting position, if not in view
        slider.$currentPage.siblings().find(element).css({
            top: '-' + dist + 'px'
        });
    },

    onSlideInit: function(e, slider) {
        var $elnext = slider.$targetPage.find(element),
            $ellast = slider.$lastPage.find(element);
        if ($elnext.length) {
            $elnext
                .css({ top: '-' + dist + 'px' })
                // animate element into it's final position
                .animate({ top: 0 }, fxtime);
        }
        if ($ellast.length) {
            // animate element out of view (down, then reset it to the
            // top when finished)
            $ellast.animate({ top: dist + 'px' }, fxtime, function() {
                $ellast.css({ top: '-' + dist + 'px' });
            });
        }
    }
});​
```